# Openshift service account can't be authorized in private registry

Tags: docker, openshift

I created a very simple image, just for the test:

```
FROM alpine:3.8
ENTRYPOINT top
```

I pushed it to a private repository on hub.docker.com.

I created secrets. I tried two different ways, but I got the same result.

```
oc create secret docker-registry pull-secret --docker-server=auth.docker.io/token --docker-username=MY_USER --docker-password=MY_PASS --docker-email=MY_EMAIL
```

or

```
oc create secret generic dockerhub --from-file=.dockerconfigjson=C:\Users\USER_NAME\.docker\config.json  --type=kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
```

The contents of the onfig.json file:

```
{
    "auths": {
        "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {
            "auth": "MY_USER_AND_PASS_BASE64_TOKEN",
            "email": "MY_EMAIL"
        }
    },
    "HttpHeaders": {
        "User-Agent": "Docker-Client/18.03.1-ce (windows)"
    },
    "credsStore": "wincred"
}
```

I added secrets to service accounts:

```
oc secrets link --for=pull default pull-secret
oc secrets link builder pull-secret
oc secrets link deployer pull-secret
```

and I tried something like this:

```
oc secrets add serviceaccount/default secrets/pull-secret --for=pull
oc secrets add serviceaccount/builder secrets/pull-secret
oc secrets add serviceaccount/deployer secrets/pull-secret
```

Then when I try to deploy an image the openshift shows that the image is available and even shows the size of the image. So, secrets work. Without secrets, there is no access to the image.

When I try to deploy an image, I get the following problem:

```
2:38:49 AM  Normal  Pulling     pulling image "docker.io/MY_USER/simple-test-image@sha256:a9d7749ce23069865a4e540862271bv8e66f9452acb33668e72029fdfdb4e9f4"

2:38:51 AM  Warning Failed  Error: ErrImagePull
2 times in the last minute

2:38:51 AM  Warning Failed  Failed to pull image "docker.io/MY_USER/simple-test-image@sha256:a9d7749ce23069865a4e540862271bv8e66f9452acb33668e72029fdfdb4e9f4": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = repository docker.io/MY_USER/simple-test-image not found: does not exist or no pull access
2 times in the last 

2:39:00 AM  Normal  Sandbox Changed     Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
7 times in the last minute

2:39:02 AM  Normal  Back-off    Back-off pulling image "docker.io/MY_USER/simple-test-image@sha256:a9d7749ce23069865a4e540862271bv8e66f9452acb33668e72029fdfdb4e9f4"
6 times in the last 

2:39:02 AM  Warning Failed  Error: ImagePullBackOff
6 times in the last minute
```

It seems that the system has access to the image, but the service accounts don't have access or don't use secrets.

I tried to deploy an image from the console (oc new-app docker.io/MY_USER/simple-test-image) and from the site, but got the same result.

I recreated the secrets, tried to edit the service accounts and much more, but nothing helped. When I change the type of repository to the public, everything works fine, but I need it private.

It seems I missed something. I would be grateful for any advice.

Comment: What do you get when you run ``oc version``? Is this Minishift, ``oc cluster up``, OpenShift Online, or some OpenShift environment set up by you or your company?

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Here is oc version \
oc v3.10.0-0.69.0 \
kubernetes v1.10.0+b81c8f8 \
features: Basic-Auth \

Server https://api.starter-us-west-2.openshift.com:443 \
openshift v3.10.9 \
kubernetes v1.10.0+b81c8f8 \


Right now it's a test free server, so I don't have a cluster, just a container. This is OpenShift Online.

Comment: Have you tried with just ``docker.io`` for ``--docker-server``? Don't use ``auth.docker.io/token``. I am not sure ``--from-file`` will work because of how docker uses the separate credentials store.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Yes, I tried docker.io but got the same result - the image was available, but I couldn’t deploy it. The error was the same, no difference. It looks like --from-file works, because the added secrets are visually visible in the OpenShift control panel and look good.

Comment: You might bring it to the attention to OpenShift community support team at https://help.openshift.com/forms/community-contact.html I don't really have the time to get in and try it myself right now.